# "Segmentation Fault" : when using xlsx npm module in node.js app on linode

Tags: node.js, segmentation-fault, npm, xlsx

I'm running a node.js app on linode server(Cent Os 7).

My app is using xlsx npm module for excel conversion and is giving  **Segmentation Fault** when my code reaches :

```
var xlsx = XLSX.read(file.data, {type: "binary"});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably running node.js v0.10.31 or higher.

I was getting this problem when switching my workplace from my macbook to a Ubuntu desktop. And after some hours searching around, I found this github issue on another repository: https://github.com/SheetJS/j/issues/4.
And it's exactly the same problem of js-xlsx.

I've downgraded my node.js to v0.10.30 and everything worked fine.
Hope this get fixed soon.

EDIT: the issue came from https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8208, which was fixed in node v0.10.32

Comment: Note that the underlying problem https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8208 was fixed in 0.10.32